# get values between quotes inside list in python

Tags: python

I have list return like

```
wks=[<Worksheet u'Categories' id:530738213>, <Worksheet u'TCS Centre' id:0>, <Worksheet u'Vismaya' id:1615183731>]
```

want values inside the quotes

Tried with this

```
import re
re.findall('"([^']*)"',wks)
```

But it's not working for the list

final output should be

```
wkslist=['Categories','TCS Centre','Vismaya']
```

Comment: How did you construct this list?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh: Its returning from worksheet function. which is returns the name of the sheets

Comment: can u add all those details in the question to reduce the guess work, also is `<Worksheet u'Categories' id:530738213>` is a string representation of an object?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh: Ok. yes its a string representation of an object

Comment: Work with the object rather than the string representation.

Comment: E.g. `names = [sheet.name for sheet in wks]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
import re

wks=["<Worksheet u'Categories' id:530738213>", "<Worksheet u'TCS Centre' id:0>", "<Worksheet u'Vismaya' id:1615183731>"]


result = []
for i in wks:
    match = re.findall(r"'(.*)'", i.strip())
    result += match

print(result)
```

output:

```
['Categories', 'TCS Centre', 'Vismaya']
```

Comment: After converting each element into string( str() ). It worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The list is constructed from objects. Each object is actually a `Worksheet` instance, represented in the list by its `__repr__` method. In order to get the value between the parenthesis, you would need to know the name of the attribute of `Worksheet`. Here's an example - Let's assume `Worksheet` looks along the lines of:

```py
class Worksheet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Categories"

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Worksheet {self.name}>"
```

In that case, you would need to extract the `name` attribute:

```py
new_list = [elem.name for elem in wks]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you must work with the string representation of these objects, you could also try something like

```
 wks=["<Worksheet u'Categories' id:530738213>", "<Worksheet u'TCS Centre' id:0>", "<Worksheet u'Vismaya' id:1615183731>"]
 [w.split("'")[1] for w in wks]
```

to get

```
 ['Categories', 'TCS Centre', 'Vismaya']
```

We split `wks` based on the occurrence of the `'` character to get 3 parts from
each element of `wks`. The one you need is the middle one which is at index `1`.